# How to source more than one bash script from a folder in another script so I can use functions from both of that scrips?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have **run.sh** script in a directory. I have also two scripts called **d1.sh** and **d2.sh** located in it's subdirectory called **deep**. I want to source both d1.sh and d2.sh in run.sh script, so I can use "test" function stored in **d2.sh**.

code of **run.sh** looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./deep/*

test
```

**d1.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "d1 is loaded"
```

**d2.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "d2 is loaded"

test() {
    echo -e "test passed!"
}
```

I execute **run.sh** with command:

```
bash run.sh
```

I get output:

```
d1 is loaded
```

So it looks like **d1.sh** script is loading, but **d2.sh** not. My question is, why is this happening and how should I do it to load all scripts stored in **./deep** folder?

Comment: `source` only takes sources one script. The rest of the arguments are passed to the script. So it will only source the first script it sees and treat all the other filenames as arguments to the first script. Use a loop or source each script individually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./deep/*;
  do
      source $file;
 done
```

Comment: Works like charm! Could you please tell me how can I do the same trick for two folders? Lets say I have folder ./deep and ./deeper Do I have to make two loops or can I use one to do it and store paths in array or something?

Comment: You can find all the files ending with sh in all directories of the current folder  and then source them, script follows,  `for file in  $(find . -type f -name "*.sh"); do  source $file; done